# Duckling encoding umlauts

Tags: python, api, character-encoding, duckling

I apply duckling for extracting and converting written numbers into digits.
when I pass the sentence in german: " **fünf sechs sieben**", it triggered an error: {'message': '**An invalid response was received from the upstream server**'}

do you know how can I encode the sentence to avoid the error? **Sentences without german "umlauts" are working fine.**

```
url = "https://duckling..../parse"

payload = f'locale=de_DE&text={input_transcript}&dims=number'
headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
    }

try:
        response = requests.post(
            url,
            data=payload,
            headers=headers,
        )
        if response.status_code == 200:
           json_response = response.json()
```

Comment: Have you tried url-encoding the payload?

Comment: yes like this:  text.encode(encoding="utf-8").decode(encoding="utf-8")  but this is not working as well

Comment: [URL quoting](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=urlencode#url-quoting)?

Comment: thanks! I applied urllib.parse.quote for encoding and this worked!